# Bamboo Deployment Versioning after Build

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo, continuous-deployment

In Bamboo the deployment project is what handles versioning but the build project, which happens first, is what handles compiling the dlls. But what if I want my build to dynamically set the version on the dll when it compiles it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to version your compiled build and not deployment. If you deploy the same build to 2 different servers, it is still the same version.

For this you can use your build number variable - `${bamboo.buildNumber}`, together with branch name if you need - `${bamboo.planRepository.branchName}`